# How i Can Ensure the current_user by passing it into Scope So that It gives me only Associated Relation Data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

In the Code I have Index Method in the NotificationsController

```
def index  
@notifications = Notification.role_ids_of_user(current_user).notifications_order_by_desc.page(params[:page])
# If i passed nil in place of current_user there should be some Error Handling How it Will done
end
```

In The Notification.rb

```
scope :role_ids_of_user, ->(current_user) { where(:role_id => current_user.pluck(:id),:state => "published") }
```

I want a Error Handling where we can perform for Current_user authentication

Comment: Doesn't `user.role_ids` return what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In the model notification.rb, instead of a one-liner scope, you could just do:

```
def self.role_ids_of_user(current_user)
  if current_user
    where(:role_id => current_user.id,:state => "published")
  else
    # throw your error or do whatever here
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `pluck' for  It shows when i Put it According to ur def

Comment: Indeed. I had just copied an pasted your where clause. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using it is introduced in Rails4.

Rails3 syntax:

scope :role_ids_of_user, lambda { |current_user| where(:role_id => current_user.pluck(:id),:state => "published") }

You can try this if you are working in rails3.